# NERDTree: Opening a file below the file explorer

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm using NERDTree and **(1) want to have the following layout** in a single window to save the resolution in the horizontal direction. Does NERDTree support such a layout? In addition, I need to **(2) arrange the display ratio** in the vertical direction.

```
-----------------------------------
|                                 |
|  File Explorer:                 |
|                                 |
|    Always open.                 |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
|                                 |
|  Multiple Files:                |
|                                 |
|    Only a single file is        |
|    displayed. You can display   |
|    a specific file in the       |
|    buffer invoking ":b [n]".    |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

By default NEDTree opens files on the right of the file explorer as follows:

```
-----------------------------------
|        |                        |
|        |                        |
|        |                        |
|  F.E.  |  Multiple Files        |
|        |                        |
|        |                        |
|        |                        |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Obligatory: [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not use nerdtree, but a quick search in the source shows following lines:

```
call s:initVariable("g:NERDTreeWinPos", "left")
call s:initVariable("g:NERDTreeWinSize", 31)
```

So i bet you can use this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "top"
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = X
```

For the ration you can do some math with the `&lines` variable.
However you will have to do this in two autocmds `VimResized` and `BufEnter` and probably `BufNew` too.
There are a lot of questions and answers about autocmd on SO so i will not explain it any further unless you need some specific help.